# How do I define a static array to member functions of a templated class?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static, function-pointers

I want to do the following :-

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename I>
class A {
  public:
    I member_;
    void f() {}
    void g() {}
    typedef void (A::*fptr) ();
    static const fptr arr[];
};

template <typename I>
A<I>::fptr A<I>::arr[] = {
  &A<I>::f,
  &A<I>::g
};
```

How do I do this?
I get the following errors :-

```
g++ memeber_func_ptr_array.cpp 
memeber_func_ptr_array.cpp:14:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘A<I>::fptr’ because ‘A<I>’ is a dependent scope
memeber_func_ptr_array.cpp:17:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
```

Comment: Did you try adding `typename` before `A<I>::fptr`?

Comment: Actually *reading* the error messages does help every so often...

Comment: I tried adding typename and got some different (and even more confusing error messages). The trick was to add const typename and not just typename.

Comment: @owagh: *Reading the error message* is something that can be done *multiple* times iteratively. Add the `typename`, get an error saying that you are declaring something else, read the error message, see where they differ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things.

1. `fptr` is a [dependent type](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) so you need `typename`:

   ```
   template <typename I>
   const typename A<I>::fptr A<I>::arr[2] = { // also note the 2 and the const
     &A<I>::f,
     &A<I>::g
   };
   ```

   And as jrok noted in the comments, your declaration is `const` so the definition must be `const` as well.
2. Client code (files that just include the header) needs to know how big the array is so you need the actual size of the array in the declaration:

   ```
   static const fptr arr[2]; // include size
   ```

   You can only use the automatic deduction of the size of the array when the array is declared and initialised in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `const typename` before `A<I>::fptr`. The `typename` is there to tell the compiler that `fptr` is a type within `A<I>`.

You might want to look at C++ Templates: The Complete Guide by Vandevoorde and Josuttis for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typename` as:

```
  template <typename I>
  typename A<I>::fptr A<I>::arr[] = { &A<I>::f, &A<I>::g };
//^^^^^^^^note this
```

It is because `fptr` is a *dependent* type.